# Scrapy Exporting to AWS S3 all the data in one CSV instead of Multiple CSV's

Tags: python, csv, amazon-s3, scrapy, feed

I am trying to export scraped data with Scrapy in two csv's to S3 using the MultiCSVItemPipeline. It works well on my computer and the data is exported in two separate csv's but when exporting to S3, all the data gets exported in one csv to S3 and two csv's on my computer.

pipeline.py

````
from itemadapter import ItemAdapter
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import csv


class MultiCSVItemPipeline(object):
    file_names = ['results','meta']
    
    
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.files = dict([ (name, open(name+'.csv','w+b')) for name in self.file_names ])
        self.exporters = dict([ (name,CsvItemExporter(self.files[name])) for name in self.file_names])
        
        [e.start_exporting() for e in self.exporters.values()]


    def close_spider(self, spider):
        [e.finish_exporting() for e in self.exporter.values()]
        [f.close() for f in self.files.values()]

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        

        item_1 = {
            'source_id': item.get('source_id'),
            'task_id': item.get('task_id'),
            'job_id':    item.get('job_id'),
            'date_posted': item.get('date_posted'),
            'timestamp': item.get('timestamp'),
            'company': item.get('company'),
            'company_id_1': item.get('company_id_1'),
            'company_id_2': item.get('company_id_2'),
            'location': item.get('location'),
            'title': item.get('title'),
            'summary': item.get('summary'),
            'full_listing_url': item.get('full_listing_url'),
            'task_url': item.get('task_url'),
            'page_url': item.get('link'),
            'timestamp': item.get('time_n')
                      

        }

        item_2 = {
                'source_id': item.get('source_id'),
                'task_id' : item.get('task_id'),
                'job_id': item.get('job_id'),
                'meta_name': item.get('meta_name'),
                'meta_value': item.get('meta_value'),
                'meta_source': item.get('meta_source'),
                'task_url': item.get('task_url'),
                'task_config': item.get('task_config'),
                'timestamp': item.get('time_n')
                
        }

               
        if item.get('meta_source') is not None:
        
            self.exporters['meta'].export_item(item_2)
        else:
            self.exporters['results'].export_item(item_1)
        return item ```


settings.py


```AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = <My_access_key>
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = <My_secret_access_key>



FEEDS = {
    's3://indeedusap/results.csv': {
                                        'format': 'csv',
                                       
                                        },
    's3://indeedusap/meta.csv': {
                                        'format': 'csv',
                                       
                                        },
    
}
````

I tried adding the s3 path to the names of the files in the pipelines but it doesn't work, I get  KeyError: 's3://indeedusap/meta'.

Comment: show the traceback but the error message is relatively clear, just need to understand _where_ it is coming from

Comment: How the code is written here I do not get any error, the only thing is that all the data gets exported in one csv to S3 and not two. 
On my computer all is ok and I get the data in the two csv